# How to change standard resources on phone/emulator

Tags: android, resources

I'm a new in Android and Java and I have the following problem. I want to change standard resources,  such as  button background, programatically to allow applications using standard buttons be displayed with custom background. My problem is - how shall I identify the path for retrieval resources on phone or emulator? And if we have permissions to access to those resources?

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can change "standard resources" for the entire device is to modify and install your own firmware.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are very helpful. But I wonder if there is any ohter way to approach this problem?

Comment: The *only* way you can change "standard resources" for the entire device is to modify and install your own firmware.